# Prove that if six natural numbers are chosen at random, then the sum or difference of two of them is divisible by 9.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Any input on how to approach this problem will be appreciated!

Comment: Input: look at the remainders of the six numbers, after division by 9.

Comment: Can it just be disproved by counterexample?

Edit: The question does say we have to prove it

Answer (score 1):

This is a very nice example of a proof by the pigeon hole principle: If you sort more than n objects into n pigeon holes, at least one pigeon hole will contain at least two objects.

Application to your problem: Let the six numbers be $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$. If two of them are divisible by 9, the result follows immediately. So let's assume that $a$ may or may not be, but none of $b,c,d,e,f$ are divisible by 9 (this is needed at the very end). Note that $$ a + x \equiv a - y \mod 9 \,\,\,\,\Rightarrow x + y \equiv 0 \mod 9$$

$$a + x \equiv a + y \mod 9 \,\,\,\,\Rightarrow x - y \equiv 0 \mod 9$$

Now consider the set of up to ten numbers $\lbrace a \pm x \,|\,x \in \lbrace b,c,d,e,f\rbrace\rbrace\,$ modulo 9 to conclude.